# remove_if with boost::bind is slow

Tags: c++, boost, ref, boost-bind, remove-if

I have a std::list of classes and want to remove entries that are marked for delete. I am using std::remove_if and erase.

```
class MyClass
{
    bool isDone(MyData& myData)
    {
        return myData.isDone();
    }

    void removeIfDone(std::list<MyData>& myList)
    {
        std::list<MyData>::iterator it =
            remove_if(myList.begin(), myList.end(), 
                  boost::bind(&MyClass::isDone, this, _1));
        myList.erase(it, myList.end());
    }
};
```

I am running on a small processor for which memory allocation and deallocation is very expensive. This remove is calling new and delete thousands of times in my application.

I have previously used `boost::ref` when passing a non-trivial variable as a bind parameter but in this case I think it is probably the creation and destruction of the functor itself or the copying of it which is causing the problem.

I would like to do something like

```
boost::bind(&MyClass::isDone, boost::ref(this), boost::ref(_1));
```

I can't find documentation on what is being created and destroyed. So my simple question is how do I make this more efficient?

Comment: have you checked if `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>` or even `std::vector<MyClass>` isn't faster than `list`? Often it is

Comment: @andyt Thank you for the suggestion. That was 4 years ago and I don't work there any more but I'm fairly sure I was using a list because I needed the benefits of a list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try replacing the call to `std::remove_if` with [`std::list::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove). The latter should only copy some pointers from the preceding and succeeding elements, instead of trying to move the elements to the end of the list, which is the cause of the multiple allocations you're seeing. An additional benefit is that since it is a member function of `std::list`, it actually removes (i.e. erases) the elements matching your criterion.

```
class MyClass
{
    bool isDone(MyData& myData)
    {
        return myData.isDone();
    }

    void removeIfDone(std::list<MyData>& myList)
    {
        myList.remove_if( boost::bind( &MyClass::isDone, this, _1 ) );
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer, `boost::bind` is completely unrelated.

Comment: Excellent answer.  boost::bind() shouldn't affect speed at all (it's just syntactic sugar)--the real culprit is the algorithm itself, as you pointed out.

Comment: On our system this made a factor of 10 difference. It's made me realise that functions in the <algorithm> library are not only generic - they work on a number of container types - but they manipulate the containers in a generic way which may not be the most efficient. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps solve your problem using a simple functor that you pass to your `std::remove_if`. This way you don't need to pass any args to it in the `remove_if` and save yourself a `boost::bind`

```
struct functor
{
public:
    bool operator()(MyData& mydata)
    { 
       return mydata.IsDone();
    }   
};

void removeIfDone(std::list<MyData>& myList)
{
   std::list<MyData>::iterator it =
     remove_if(myList.begin(), myList.end(), 
         functor()); //call operator() on functor
     myList.erase(it, myList.end());
}
```

An example that [compiles here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c3586eb76ec3c443fbfb2d571ebdcbd1-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94)