# Don't understand results of std::remove in C++ STL

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I was reading Josuttis "The C++ Standard Library, 2nd ed.". In section 6.7.1 author explains that the code given below will give unexpected results. I still don't how `std::remove()` functions, and why I am getting this strange result. (Though I understood that you need to use `std::erase()` in order to actually remove elements, and it is actually better to use `list::erase()` rather than combination of `std::remove()` & `std::remove()).

```
list<int> coll;
// insert elements from 6 to 1 and 1 to 6
for (int i=1; i<=6; ++i) {
     coll.push_front(i);
     coll.push_back(i);
}

// print
copy (coll.cbegin(), coll.cend(), // source
      ostream_iterator<int>(cout," ")); // destination
      cout << endl;

// remove all elements with value 3
remove (coll.begin(), coll.end(), // range
        3); // value
// print (same as above)
```

and the results are

```
pre:  6 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 6
post: 6 5 4 2 1 1 2 4 5 6 5 6 (???)
```

Comment: how do you print it after remove?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, I just added the code ! see the print function

Comment: See the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456870/stl-remove-doesnt-work-as-expected

Comment: All element with value 3 is overwritten by the following elements. Didn't you see the figure ?

Comment: @newprint Also note that in your case calling `list::remove` is [far better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278108/remove-if-with-boostbind-is-slow/15281230#15281230) than using the erase-remove idiom.

Comment: P.S. Improper use of the remove() function is very common phenomenon. This error can see in TortoiseSVN, IPP Samples, Chromium and so on. :) http://www.viva64.com/en/examples/V530/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [explanation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) should help:

> Removing is done by shifting the elements in the range in such a way
>   that elements to be erased are overwritten. Relative order of the
>   elements that remain is preserved and the physical size of the
>   container is unchanged. Iterators pointing to an element between the
>   new logical end and the physical end of the range are still
>   dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have unspecified values.
>   A call to remove is typically followed by a call to a container's
>   erase method, which erases the unspecified values and reduces the
>   physical size of the container to match its new logical size.

Note that the return value from `std::remove()` is the iterator that represents the new *end*. Therefore, calling `std::erase()` on this new end and the old end will free your excess space.

Comment: Almost correct - if you call `erase` with only the new end, it will only erase one element. You need to call the two-parameter version, with the new end and the old end.

Answer (score 4):

`std::remove` doesn't actually shorten the list. It can't - as it only gets iterators and not the container itself.

What it does is copies the remaining values so that you get them in the beginning of the container. But the final elements of the container (in your case - the last two: '5' and '6') are actually still there..

After using `std::remove` you **have** to shorten to container yourself to remove the remaining "junk" copies.

Answer (score 3):

To quote from [everyone's favorite c++ website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/):

> The function cannot alter the properties of the object containing the
>   range of elements (i.e., it cannot alter the size of an array or a
>   container): The removal is done by replacing the elements that compare
>   equal to val by the next element that does not, and signaling the new
>   size of the shortened range by returning an iterator to the element
>   that should be considered its new past-the-end element.

So `std::remove` doesn't change the size of the list. It removes the matching elements and returns you an iterator that represents the new end of the list. To actually erase the extraneous elements, you then need to do:

```
auto it = remove(coll.begin(), coll.end(), 3);
coll.erase(it, coll.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

You asked the algorithm to remove "3" element. So, while enumerating the container the algo shifts the content if something is removed from the middle. Such shift occurs 2 times in your case, this is why you see "5 6" elements at the end (because actual end was moved to 2 items forward). Then, "std::erase" will fix the issue with tail zombies.